# The mean value theorem for vectors in m dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Let A ⊂ R<sup>n</sup> be open. Suppose f : A → R<sup>m</sup> is a differentiable mapping, and x, y ∈ A satisfy that the line segment joining x and y lies in A. Prove that for any v ∈ R<sup>m</sup>, there exists a convex combination of x and y, denoted as z, such that v · f(y) − f(x) = v · [Df(z) · (y − x)]

what I've done so far is:
for $g:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ let $g(\lambda)=f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y) \therefore g(1)=f(y), g(0)=f(x)$ By the chain rule, $g:(0,1)\rightarrow R^m$ is differentiable as $f$ is differentiable $\therefore Dg(\lambda)=Df((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)\cdotp (y-x)$ as $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y$ is a convex combination we show it as z therefore $Dg(\lambda)=Df(z)\cdotp (y-x)$ therefore $v\cdotp Dg(\lambda)=v\cdotp Df(z)\cdot (y-x)$

How do I get $Dg(\lambda)$ to $f(x)-f(y)$ without changing the left hand side of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem on *one* variable,

$$
f(y) - f(x) = g(1) - g(0) = g'(c)(1-0) = Df_z(y-x)
$$

with $z = g(c) = (1-c)x + cy$.

Comment: Then I just take the dot product of both sides with v?

Comment: That works, I think :)